# How do I change the format of the output from a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html

**Javascript:**

```
window.onload=function(){
  chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(backgroundPage){ 
  var currentUrl = backgroundPage.tabURL;

  console.log(currentUrl);



    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/post?url=websiteurl.com', false ); 
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
    document.getElementById('currentUrl').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    return xmlHttp.responseText;

 })

};
```

This code produces an output that looks like:

```
[Value1],[Value2],[Value3].
```

How do I change it so the output is formatted like:

```
  **[Value1],

    [Value2],

    [Value3],**
```

with one word per line and in bold? I'm sure its really easy, but I don't know how to go about doing it?

**HTML:**

```
<div id='currentUrl'>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>


        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS to make it bold. You can use `join()` if it's an array or `replace()` if it's a string to replace the `,` with `,<br>`

Answer (score 0):

First to replace all the dots to commas you can use:

```
var stringReg= new RegExp(stringtoreplace, '.');
targetstring = targetstring.replace(stringReg, ',');
```

Then if you want to add new lines within your string you can add:

```
"This is my string \nThis is a newline"
```

If you need to loop each element you can just append the newline string to the end of each element. You can loop the string and every time you find a "]," you can add the newline character to the right of it, you can use regex for this:

```
var stringReg= new RegExp(stringtoreplace, '],');
targetstring = targetstring.replace(stringReg, '],\n');
```

You can append a string to the front by doing:

```
var result = str1.concat("**");
```

Or you could simply do this instead:

```
var startString = "**"
var endString = "**"
var mainString = "This is the main string"
var newString = startString + mainString + endString
```

For making it bold, use CSS

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, you can use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) functions to produce the desired output.

```js
const strgVal = '[Value1],[Value2],[Value3]';
let fromatedSr = '**' + strgVal.split(',').join(',\n') + '**';
console.log(fromatedSr);
```